# How to use both rtl and ltr bootstrap 5 sass styles in a project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using bootstrap5 scss.

I include styles for ltr as standard: `@import "~ bootstrap / scss / bootstrap";`

**Question:** how to connect or enable `rtl` bootstrap 5 scss styles?

From the instructions, nothing is clear, except how to connect via link in the standard way, but it is necessary in scss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated answer:

What I think is missing from the documents is the fact that **if you are importing the scss version**, then you need to have postcss installed and configured. AND you also need an rtl plugin. I had success with [postcss-rtlcss](https://github.com/elchininet/postcss-rtlcss).

So just install postcss & postcss-rtlcss:

`npm i -D postcss postcss-rtlcss`

Then in your project root (or in the app dir if you are using nx) add this config file named `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['postcss-rtlcss']
};
```

And now you just run your project and should have rtl working perfectly!

### Old answer (don't use, not that great):

Import normal bootstrap & import rtl with an rtl selector:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

[dir='rtl'] {
  @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-utilities.rtl.min';
}
```

NOTE: If you import `bootstrap.rtl.min` it will override your color variables (beacuse it's the compiled css with the values already baked)

NOTE#2: I still don't think this is how bootstrap intended rtl to be used. because right now if you have `me-2` on an element in ltr it will have 2 margin on the right but in rtl it will have margins on both right and left ! as the rtl code just added the rtl and didn't change the rtl instruction.

Idealy we would have a full version of rtl bootstrap BUT in SCSS which would fix most of our problems. I will update this answer as soon as I find out more.

I found that just importing `utilities` handles most of my rtl needs. I think you can import other files as you see fit just keep the overriding in mind.

Answer (score 2):

We can setup with react bootstrap 5 as below steps.

##### Setup 1: npm install scss

##### Setup 2: create file `main.scss`

##### Setup 3: in main.scss file

1. add `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-utilities";`
2. copy all style from `../node_modules/bootstrap/dis/css/bootstrap.rtl.css`
3. add `[dir="rtl"] { paste all style here}`
4. add `[dir="ltr"] {@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";}`
5. save the file

##### Setup 4: import "./main.scss" in index.tsx or App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

> You're not supposed to use both CSS files in the same page, [as
> mentioned in our docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#required-html). You may have a look at our starter template
> in that page, using a single CSS file.
>
> If you need RTL and LTR at the same time, you'll need to [use Sass and
> tweak your build a bit](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#required-html). But our official build (thus releases
> available through a CDN) won't work with both directions in the same
> page.
>
> We plan to add an example template with some bidi contents in
> [#32330](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32330) — but it's not done yet. I close this issue since it works
> as intended.
>
> We'd be pleased to get any insights or suggestions you'd have to help
> us improve our docs or template example, though. :)
>
> Edit: I see the code you shared doesn't reflect what happens in the
> CodePen you provided. Please update your CodePen with the code you
> tried if you need any support.

This is answer from [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33065).

Comment: those. at the moment there is no such possibility ...

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT INFO:** I copied this section from [official Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#ltr-and-rtl-at-the-same-time):

**LTR and RTL at the same time**

Need both LTR and RTL on the same page? Thanks to [RTLCSS String Maps](https://rtlcss.com/learn/usage-guide/string-map/), this is pretty straightforward. Wrap your @imports with a class, and set a custom rename rule for RTLCSS:

```
/* rtl:begin:options: {
    "autoRename": true,
    "stringMap":[ {
        "name": "ltr-rtl",
        "priority": 100,
        "search": ["ltr"],
        "replace": ["rtl"],
        "options": {
            "scope": "*",
            "ignoreCase": false
        }
    } ]
} */
.ltr {
    @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
}
/*rtl:end:options*/
```

> Edge cases and known limitations While this approach is
> understandable, please pay attention to the following:
>
> When switching .ltr and .rtl, make sure you add dir and lang
> attributes accordingly. Loading both files can be a real performance
> bottleneck: consider some [optimization](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/), and maybe try to [load one of
> those files asynchronously](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/). Nesting styles this way will prevent our
> form-validation-state() mixin from working as intended, thus require
> you tweak it a bit by yourself. [See #31223](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31223).